In finite fields, generators of $F^*$ under automorphisms in Galois group are also generators

Let $F$ be a finite field with characteristic $p$ and denote $F^*$ the group of invertible elements of $F$. Show that if $a \in F^*$ is a generator, then so is $\sigma (a)$, for all $\sigma \in \textrm{Gal}(F/F_p)$.

My attempt so far:
Since $F$ has characteristic $p$, $|F^*|=p^n-1$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$. And so for all $\sigma \in \textrm{Gal}(F/F_p)$:
$$ 
(\sigma(a))^{p^n-1}=\sigma(a^{p^n-1})=\sigma(1)=1
$$
Hence the order of $\sigma(a)$ divides $p^n-1$. Now I want to show it equals $p^n-1$. I've tried using the fact that $x^n-1$ splits to $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(x-\zeta ^i) $ for $\zeta=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$ but I feel like this is an overkill (and I'm not even sure it's relevant). Would appericiate any help.

I quite like Mike's approach (+1). For a different one: Are you familiar with the facts A) $\sigma$ must be a power of the Frobenius automorphism, B) if $G$ is any group and $g\in G$ has order $n$, then the order of $g^k$ is equal to $n/\gcd(n,k)$?

We say an element $a$ generates $(F)^×$ if every element $y \in (F)^×$, or equivalently, every nonzero element $y$ in $F$, can be written $y=a^r$ for some intrger $r$. And here, by a proper divisor $e$ of an integer $r$, we mean any positive integer $e < r$ that divides $r$, including $e=1$.
HINT:

If an element $c \in F$ is a generator of a field $(F)^×$ [of cardinality $p^l$], then there is no proper divisor $e$ s.t. the equation $c^e-1=0$ holds. Conversely, if there is no proper divisor $e$ of $p^l-1$ s.t.$c^e-1=0$, then $c$ is a generator of $(F)^×$.

So then, as $a$ generates $(F)^×$, there is no proper divisor $e$ of $p^l-1$ s.t. the equation $a^e-1=0$ is satisfied.

But, if $a$ isn't the root of a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_p$, then neither is $\sigma(a)$ the root of that polynomial either? What then does 1. and 2. above say about $\sigma(a)$ then? [As $a$ generates $(F)^×$, there is no proper divisor $e$ of $p^l-1$ s.t. the equation $a^e-1=0$ holds, as already observed in 2. above. Thus, [as the coefficients of $x^e-1$ are clearly in $\mathbb{F}_p$] there is no such $e$ that the equation $(\sigma(a))^e-1=0$ holds either. And so also by 1., the element $\sigma(a)$ must generate $(F)^×$.]



If I understand correctly, since $\sigma(a)$ is a root of $x^e-1$, we have:
$$ 0=(\sigma(a))^e-1=\sigma(a^e-1)$$ which implies $a^e=1$, contradicting the assumption that $e$ is a proper divisor of $p^l-1$?

Well I am having trouble following your comment. I will rephrase my answer. If $\sigma(a)$ does not generate $F$ then $(\sigma(a))^e -1=0$ for some $e$ that is a proper divisor of $p^l-1$. But that implies $a^e-1=0$ for that $e$. Which contradicts the fact that $a$ generates $F^*$ i.e., every nonzeroelement $y$ in $F$ can be written $y=a^r$ for some integer $r$

To address your comment [I think I see better now] we indeed have $a^e-1=0$, which contradicts the assumption that $a$ generates every nonzero element in $F$.([Instead $a$ only generates at most $e$ of them.]

I apologize @RatherAmusing I should have said originally that $c$ generates $(F)^×$ iff $c^e-1\not = 0$ for all proper divisors of $p^l-1$ . I edited

An automorphisms in the Galois group induces an automorphism of the (cyclic) multiplicative group. An automorphism of a cyclic group carries generators to generators.
